# Adding two Labels but they have no space between them

Tags: java, vaadin

I have added to my layout two labels:

```
Div container = new Div();
container.add(new Label(getTranslation(MessageConstants.SOME_DESCRIPTION)));
container.add(new Label(getTranslation(MessageConstants.MORE_DESCRIPTION_TEMPLATE, valueToAdd)));
add(container);
```

But this results in having no space between the labels. This looks bad, see image:

[image: Screenshot]

What is the best way to avoid this without combining both translation labels?

Comment: An alternative to `Div` is to use [HorizontalLayout](https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/ds/components/basic-layouts/#horizontal-layout) where you will get spacing and much more out of the box. I use `VerticalLayout` and `HorizontalLayout` all the time and almost never `Div` anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways to add a space between the two labels. But one way is to add some right padding to the first component like so:

```
Div container = new Div();
Label firstLabel = new Label("first");
firstLabel .getStyle().set("padding-right", "10px");
container.add(firstLabel);
container.add(new Label("second"));
```

Answer (score 0):

and should not -> please see Browser Inspector (padding, margins)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).